# multithread std::shared_ptr read / write with sigsegv

Tags: multithreading, c++11, smart-pointers

a global shared_ptr g_ptr=null;
then in thread 1, call `init()` set g_ptr=make_shared();

after that, has other thread x use `write()`

```
void write()
{
   if(g_ptr)
   {
       g_ptr->dosomething();// g_ptr.get() has a std::FILE _fd;
    }
}
```

then the program end.
the program is

in thread 1, the global g_ptr has destory.
but in other thread, func write is doing,but the _fd is set to nullptr.
so the program segmentaion fault.

both init() and write() are interface, called by customer.

how can i avoid this program?
use the raw pointer and provide a close() api ,may be ok.
except this, how can i resolve this program with use smart pointer。
thanks.

Comment: Don't describe your code in prose; show the actual code. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].